# How can i create a uiview that looks like the view in mail.app

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiview, uiwebview

I need to create a uiview that looks like the one to display mails in the mail.app on iphone.

It looks, that the view is something like a UIWebView, but there is a header-view to display From, To and Subject. This header is non-zoomable and scrolls only by the y-axis.

Is there a way to create such a header-view in the UIWebView...

// sorry for bad english

Comment: Post a screenshot please. I haven't used the mail app since gmail got really good.

Comment: http://img220.imageshack.us/img220/249/screenshotmail.png

Here is a screenshot from the mail-app. It looks realy like the hole view is a WebView (look at the typical shadow).

Answer (score 3):

It appears to be a UITableView with a row for "From" a row for the subject and a row with a UIWebView as a subview for the message body.  The "Details" button seems to reveal another row with the "To" information.